# Limit inherited permissions in subfolders

Tags: inheritance, active-directory, windows-10, network-drive

We have a drive being shared across multiple departments, and some of the information being stored does not need to be accessed by all users who have permission.

The directory looks like this: \Server\share\Folder\Sub-1\Sub-2

The goal is to have specific permissions from 'Share' down to the 'Sub-1' level, then have the ability to create the 'Sub-2' folder without inherited permissions. Ideally, we would be able to have an alternate set of perms for the 'Sub-2' folder, further limiting access to certain data.

I have disabled inheritance at the 'Sub-1' level, but folders created in 'Sub-1' still inherit perms.

How can I limit inherited permissions within subfolders, and have the configuration persist and apply to folders in the future?